# UIPickerView Delegate and DataSource methods not getting called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uipickerview

I want to display PickerView when I click the button.
I have a view which has 3 buttons. In the corresponding actions to the buttons, I have alloc'ed and init'ed the pickerView as follows:
     pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
Also I have added the PickerView to the Subview as follows:
     [self.view addSubview:pickerView];

I've also subclass'ed my class with UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate as follows:
     MyClass : UIViewController

By NSLoging i saw that PickerView DataSource and Delegate methods are not getting called.
When I click(TouchUpInside) the button, the view shows up pickerView with origin=(0,0) which should be at bottom and pickerView appears total Black. I fixed the PickerView's frame by using:
     pickerView.frame = CGRectmake(0,180,320,260);

I googled to check when the pickerView's DataSource and Delegate method are called but I couldn't find the proper answer.

I also tried the "hidden" property here as follow:
 In viewDidLoad method:
     pickerView.hidden = YES;
 In the method which is called after clicking button:
     pickerView.hidden = NO;

Help me please. I'm new to Objective C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your picker programmatically - did you actually set its delegate and dataSource?

```
// Assuming that delegate and data source is controller where picker is created
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Done. Thank you so much. But if i comment the picker.frame the pickerView frame appears at top. Can you please explain why this is happening? Also simply connecting the dataSource and Delegate of PickerView to the File's Owner is of use or not?

Comment: @Krishna, if you create picker in IB you can make delegate and data source connections there, but in your example you create it programmatically... By default picker's frame will have zero origin so if you want to position it somewhere else you need to set frame manually - as you did

Comment: any view will have zero rect frame by default if created with alloc/init but as UIPickerView has standard predefined dimensions (at least height) only frame origin is initialized to zero in your case

Comment: Thats great. Thank you again. Also i've alloc'ed and init'ed the pickerView in the method called by the Button. So this shouldn't be a issue right?

Comment: @Krishna, yes that should be fine. Just make sure that you release your picker to avoid memory leak. You can do that right after it is added to superview

Comment: Yes I did so. :)
Thank you so much for your support.